# Tricks to speed up page load time in PHP

Tags: php, performance

I know of these two tricks for speeding page load time up some:

```
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 1);
```

which turns on compression

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
```

which implicitly flushes the output buffer, meaning as soon as anything is output it is immediately sent to the user's browser. This one's a tad tricky, since it just creates the illusion that the page is loading quickly while in actuality it takes the same amount of time and the data is just being shown faster.

What other php tricks are there to make your pages load (or appear to load) faster?

Comment: Ensuring your host server is a fast machine, plenty of memory, on a very good, well-peered connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to ensure that your script isn't creating/destroying unnecessary variables and make everything as efficient as possible.  After that, you can look into a caching service so that the server does not have to reparse specific parts of a page.

If all that doesn't make it as fast as you need it to be, you can even "compile" the php code.  Facebook does this to support faster load times.  They created something called "HipHop for PHP" and you can read about it at: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/358/

There are other PHP compilers you can use to help.

If all this fails, then I suggest you either recode the website in a different language, or figure out why it is taking so long (more specifically, WHAT is causing it to take so long) and change that part of the website.

Comment: Creating/destroying a variable in PHP is essentially a zero-cost event. It takes so little time to do `$useless_var = 1;` that you have to be a Facebook-sized operation to see any difference. Now, instantiating a complex object, or doing a useless database connection... that's where you can get some gains.

Comment: I obviously was not talking about "$useless_var = 1".  Creating variables that store PHP objects (which are inefficient within themselves), or variables that store arrays of a million items was what I was talking about.  Not simple variables.

Comment: I dunno, I've got fast servers and every page loads in 1-5ms, but one, which loads in even 100-300ms! This page uses 10 files to load, but that isn't the case, because other pages use 5 and it still runs fast. What is weird - this is the only page on my site using SQL. Can anyone explain to me, what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, I realised that the page was getting sizes of 6 images every time the page runs using `getimagesize`. Well... That wasn't good practice, now it is only made when it is really needed.

Answer (score 5):

It is always better to define a **real** bottleneck and then try to avoid it.

The way to follow any trick that is supposed to make something faster without understanding whether you have the problem or not - is **always a wrong way**.

Comment: There are no 'bottlenecks' in the script. Is it wrong to speed up something which works?

Comment: @Cyclone: does your script satisfy the requirements of the loading speed, resources usage, etc etc?

Comment: It loads quickly, I am searching for ways to make it load even faster. It's been optimized logically, but there's no reason it can't go a bit faster. Those two examples I posted sped it up, surely there are some other tricks?

Answer (score 1):

There are some that can speed your website(code custmoization)

1) If you’re looping through an array, for example, count() it beforehand, store the value in a variable, and use that for your test. This way, you avoid needlessly firing the test function with every loop iteration.

2) use build in function instead of custom function

3) put JavaScript function and files at bottom of file

4) use caching

Answer (score 0):

Among the best tricks to speed up PHP page loads is to use as little PHP as possible, i.e. use a PHP cache/accelerator such as Zend or APC, or cache as much as you can yourself. PHP that does not need to be parsed again is faster, and PHP that does not run at all is still faster.

The same goes (maybe even more so) for database. Use as few queries as possible. If you can combine two queries into one, you save one round trip.